# Insert Numeric Number Till Col"B" used range

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote a code that will insert just number `"1"` in `Col"D"` whenever any value is insert in `Col"B"` rows.

Like this below image.

[image]

If i insert any value in col"B" row 48 then code will put 1 in Col"D" row 48.

But my code is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub insert1()
For i = 31 To Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
Sheet1.Cells(i, 4) = 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You code is okay and working fine to me.

Comment: I really do not know @Harun24HR why its not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try do the same in worksheet change event. i think it's simpler way.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 30 Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then Target.Offset(, 1).Value = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: disadvantage of this solution is that if you select many rows in that column and delete them return error (in this version) but u can endocde procedure in that case

Answer (score 1):

1. With your code,  you need insert value to cell B48 before macro insert(1) is executed. Step by step as below:

   - Step 1: add value for B48
   - Step 2: Run macro insert(1) => D48 will have value 1
2. If you want D48 = 1 when put value to B48 immediately, you only need to use simple formula:

> = IF(B48 <> "", 1,"")

for D48